# Why do I get dereference of a possibly null reference warning when using non-short-circuit AND operator?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have a method like this, which is a simplified version of some logic in the production code:

```
static void Foo(int a, int b, string x, string y)
{
     if (a > 100 && b < 50 && (x != null) & (y != null))
     {
          Console.WriteLine(y.Length);
     }
}
```

I get a "Dereference of a possibly null reference" error when accessing the `y.Length`.

If I change `&` to `&&`, the warning goes away. I couldn't figured it out why at first glance, then I thought it may be because the `&` operator is overloadable, so the behaviour might change and possibly it could evaluate to `true` even when the `y` is null. Is my assumption correct or am I missing something else?

Note: I can reproduce this in an app that targets .NET Core 3.1 or .NET Standard 2.0 using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - I get no warning.

Comment: I think it's just that the compiler is not smart enough to spot this. The compiler is hardcoded to recognise `&&`, but not `&`.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio/C# compiler are you using?

Comment: @MatthewWatson are you sure nullable checks are enabled? try adding "#nullable enable" to the start of the file.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I missed

Comment: It will probably have a similar answer to this related (but different) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306751/why-does-this-code-give-a-possible-null-reference-return-compiler-warning

Comment: This is an instance of https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons the compiler doesn't recognize this pattern. The most obvious is just engineering effort. Using `&`/`|` for boolean logic is just seen as less common than `&&`/`||` and therefore other things were prioritized over full support for `&`/`|` in flow analysis.

The other reason is that there would actually be a complexity cost to supporting this in nullable analysis. Consider the following admittedly contrived example: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANnAJiA1AHwMQwCuKKEwKApgAQUxmUCwAUMwGaEwDGAFESXFT5oqAe0IIqAfQCUAbmbMAAgBYq7LtwDCAfioAPATqoBPAWImaqAL2nMA3sypOqUVlW56qAQgC8g4ihUAGRqHJwAjNxWVH7GMfrS0lQA9MlUAM4AFmIo6FQA7hAATjCipQDkcX565Y7ODkzOTfoAdAAqIgDKCEWwAObccilphSXpAsDiVAAOFEWZENPpGdnE6DDlCHXNJu1dPf2DssMFxTDjVJMSs/OLy1k565vbVAC+zO8sTMAiIoHqEW4ImAACsKJwELpgSCkj4AHxUHqECjyL6KABMVE09heigAzFiqABJGAwOZUOxUPoUBDHdI046fJq4gmaQYvBo7JwkslFeIITJQdKopqfV5AA)

```cs
func(null, null, out _);

void func(C? x, C? y, out C z)
{
    if (x != null & func1(z = y = x)) // should warn on 'y = x'
    {
        x.ToString(); // warns, but perhaps shouldn't
        y.ToString(); // warns, but perhaps shouldn't
    }
}

bool func1(object? obj) => true;

class C
{
    public C Inner { get; set; }
    
    public C()
    {
        Inner = this;
    }
}
```

- After visiting the expression `x != null`, the state of `x` is "not null when true", and "maybe null when false".
- When we visit `func1(z = y = x)`, we have to assume the worst case--`x` may be null, since we get there regardless of whether `x != null` was true or false. Because of this we have to give a warning on assignment to non-nullable out parameter `z`.
- Then, after we finish visiting the `&` operator, we have to assume that if the result was true, then all the operands returned true, and otherwise any of the operands could have returned false.
- But hold on! Now if we have to assume that the operands all returned true, that means `x` was really not-null all along, and because `x` was assigned to `y`, that `y` was really not-null all along. The only practical way to account for this in this particular kind of analysis is to visit `func1(z = y = x)` a **second time**, but with an initial state where `x != null` was true.

In other words, visiting a `&` operator with full handling of nullable conditional states requires visiting the right-hand side twice--once assuming the worst-case result from the left side to produce diagnostics for it, and again assuming the left side was true, so that we can produce a final state for the operator. In contrived examples this effect can be compounding, such as `x != null & (y != null & z != null)`, where we end up having to visit `z != null` 4 times.

In order to sidestep this complexity, we've opted to not make nullable analysis work with `&`/`|` at this time. The short-circuiting behavior of `&&`/`||` means they don't suffer from the problems described above, so it's actually simpler to make them work correctly.