# Fixing "CS8603: Possible null reference return" in method override

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

With the following code

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "");
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

the compiler tells me at `return default;` that I have a CS8603 "Possible null reference return" which is true. However if I append a `?` to the return type of that method so that reads (like the abstract method) `protected override T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")` the compiler tells me

- CS0508 'Derived.GetValue(string)': return type must be 'T' to match overridden member 'Base.GetValue(string)'.
- CS0453 The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'.

How do I tell the compiler my intent that `GetValue<T>` might return a null reference and not that the return type of that method should be `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: Can `T` be limited to only classes or you need to support both reference and value types?

Comment: `T` should be allowed to be anything - both reference and value types.

Comment: I would have expected that you could perform a `default(T) is null` check and that would satisfy the compiler, but it turns out that it is not sufficient. According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328672/1165998, it doesn't seem like this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to place the `[return: MaybeNull]` attribute on the method override as follows:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
protected override T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
  return default;
}
```

The compiler now no more lists warning CS8603.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#default-constraint) generic constraint to make it compile:

```cs
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "");
}

class Derived : Base
{
    protected override T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") where T : default
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

But for value types `default(T)` will be returned not `default(Nullable<T>)` so it needs to be invoked with nullable value type for type parameter to achieve desired behaviour.

You can try to workaround by having 2 methods with different type constraints and dummy `T? == null` parameter:

```cs
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", T? _ = null) where T : struct;
    public abstract T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", T? _ = null) where T : class;
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", T? _ = null) where T : struct
    {
        return default;
    }
    public override T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "", T? _ = null) where T : class
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

But it's up to you to decide how usable/ugly this is)

Answer (score 0):

Returning `T?` instead of `T` worked for me.

```
protected override T? GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
  return default;
}
```

Or, remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your `.csproj` file