# Null-Forgiving operator still showing warning

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have the following method to override ToString()

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (HasNoValue)
            return "No value";

        return Value!.ToString();
    }
```

If HasNoValue returns true, the value property contains null so "No Value" is returned.

The HasNoValue property (and HasValue) looks like this:

```
public bool HasValue => value != null;

public bool HasNoValue => !HasValue;
```

So if NoHasValue is false I know value is not Null. As you can see I've added the null-forgiving operator on the value property before the call to ToString()

I have Nullable enable within my project `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

However, I still receive the following warning:

> Warning   CS8603  Possible null reference return.

Why am I receiving this warning if I've added the null-forgiving operator?

Comment: The compiler is warning you about you could return a null value at run time. The null-forgiving operator has no effect at run time. It only affects the compiler's static flow analysis.

Comment: Hi there, I understand it has no effect at runtime. But I thought the point of using the null-forgiving operator was for me to tell the compiler that I know the value will never be null so suppress the warning?

If not, how can I suppress the warning?

Comment: Note that `object.ToString` returns `string?`, so really you should be returning `string?` to match that.

Comment: @Sun You told to compiler that Value is not null, but ToString can return null

Comment: @Sun there is a full analysis of how the compiler behaves in Jon Skeet's answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306751/why-does-this-code-give-a-possible-null-reference-return-compiler-warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that `Object.ToString()` returns `string?`, so you need the null-forgiving operator at the end of the `.ToString()` call

You can use the `MemberNotNullWhen` attribute to tell the compiler that the `Value` property won't be null when the `HasNoValue` property is false

```
[MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(HasNoValue))]
public object? Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi there, just tried this and I still receive the warning.

Comment: @Sun updated answer; `Object.ToString()` returns `string?`