# How can I put a null check in a lambda operator?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a EF model where it has the following property:

```
public Uri? LinkedIn { get; set; }
```

In my IEntityTypeConfiguration.Configure I have:

```
builder.Property(e => e.LinkedIn).HasConversion(v => v.ToString(), v => new Uri(v));
```

I get a warning that the v in the v.ToString() might be null. But if I change it to:

```
builder.Property(e => e.LinkedIn).HasConversion(v => v?.ToString(), v => new Uri(v));
```

I get an error saying I can't have a null check in a lambda operator. I've tried parens, and explicit check, etc and it's unhappy with all of them.

Now can I do this? This is in EntityFramework Core but I think that's irrelevant to this question.

Comment: What happens if you do something like `v => v?.ToString()??string.Empty`?  What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the source type is nullable (`Uri?`), the target type should also be nullable (`string?`), hence the conversion should resolve to `HasConversion<Uri?, string?>`.

In other words, both expressions should accept nullable type argument and return nullable type result. In your case

```cs
.Property(e => e.LinkedIn)
.HasConversion(
    v => v != null ? v.ToString() : null,
    v => v != null ? new Uri(v) : null);
```

This eliminates the warnings in EF Core 7.0 project with NRT enabled. If you still get warnings, you probably are using older EF Core version, where not all APIs were properly NRT annotated.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve what you need in the old fashioned way:

Instead of

```cs
v => v?.ToString()
```

use

```cs
v => v == null ? "" : v.ToString()
```

According to this site (https://shiftkeysoftware.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/you-cannot-use-a-null-propagating-operator-in-an-expression-tree-lambda/), the reason for this behavior is, that your code needs to be translated to sql and the ef core provider doesn't support the *new* syntax.

This seems plausible, since this can be compiled without complaining:

```cs
// no ef involved; just c# code
Func<string, object> conversion = v => v?.ToString();
```

Comment: I was 100% I had tried that before asking here. But I tried again based on your suggestion. And it works. So I was doing something wrong when I tried that before. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the compiler this value will never be null using the Null-Forgiving Operator, just add a `!` after `v` like this

`builder.Property(e => e.LinkedIn).HasConversion(v => v!.ToString(), v => new Uri(v));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70759532

Comment: It can be null. The property is of type Uri? not Uri.