# Dereference of a possibly null reference on String Trim()

Tags: c#

This might be a silly qeustion.

I am not sure why I am getting the below warning on `txtMiddleName.Text.Trim()`  but not on the other textBox controls.

```
// Set Full Name Text
txtFullName.Text = txtFirstName.Text.Trim() + " " + 
                   txtMiddleName.Text.Trim() + " " + 
                   txtLastName.Text.Trim();
```

**Warning   CS8602  Dereference of a possibly null reference.**

[image]

**Updated**

The textbox(s) were declared automatically when designing WinForms

```
this.txtLastName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
this.label13 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.label12 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.label11 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.txtMiddleName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
this.txtFirstName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

Comment: You would have to show how txtMiddleName is declared.

Comment: please refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306751/why-does-this-code-give-a-possible-null-reference-return-compiler-warning

Comment: I have updated the q to include the declaration

Comment: @Unis - That's where it is instantiated, not where it is declared.

Comment: There'll be an earlier piece of your code that does something else with `txtFirstName.Text` and `txtLastName.Text` such that it's already established at this point that they cannot be null.

Comment: Thank you all, your comments and hint did help. So the `txtMiddleName .Text` actually gets assigned to Entity Property eariler in the code which is actually nullable.